# App crashing when fetching NSObjects from background

Tags: swift, core-data, grand-central-dispatch, nsnotificationcenter, nsfetchrequest

I have a notification with `NotificationCenter.default` that triggers a prune method which crashes when trying to fetch from my store. This is the method:

```
@objc fileprivate func pruneBooks() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

        let context = cdStack.getManagedObjectContext()
        context.perform {
            do{
                let request = NSFetchRequest<Book>(entityName: "Book")
                let result = try context.fetch(request)\\ <----- CRASHES HERE
                //DO STUFF
            }catch{
                // Handle Error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what my `getManagedObjectContext` method looks like:

```
func getManagedObjectContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {


    let thread = Thread.current

    if thread.isMainThread {
        return mainMOC
    }

    let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    childContext.parent = mainMOC

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(didReceiveChildContextDidSave(notification:)),
                                           name: .NSManagedObjectContextDidSave,
                                           object: childContext)

    return childContext
}
```

I have not found a way to duplicate this crash I'm just getting it in apple crash reports. Here is the backtrace:

[image]

Book is defiantly and entity and is named Book, so I know that is not the issue. Also, I am confused as to why it is not going to the catch instead of crashing.

Note: The app is for iOS 9 and up which is why I'm not using `NSPersistentContainer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/using_core_data_in_the_background) of Apple's documentation. The problem you're facing is caused by the fact that you are creating a background queue yourself, while the `ManagedObjectContext` has its own. This queue can be accessed through the `perform` method, which executes your block on that queue (so in the background). If I'm correct, you should remove the first line of your `pruneBooks` function, so that it looks like this:

```
@objc fileprivate func pruneBooks() {
    let context = cdStack.getManagedObjectContext()
    context.perform {
        do{
            let request = NSFetchRequest<Book>(entityName: "Book")
            let result = try context.fetch(request)\\ <----- CRASHES HERE
            //DO STUFF
        }catch{
            // Handle Error
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Manually examining the thread like this to decide what context to return is not a good idea.

The caller should already know what context it needs, so just ask for it. Copy the PersistentContainer approach and have `viewContext` and `newBackgroundContext` methods which return exactly that.

Your migration path will be easier too when you eventually ditch iOS 9.

-

Also there is no need to manually dispatch to a background thread, a private context already has its own queue that it will execute the `.perform {}` blocks on.